# Overlay TextView at bottom of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListView that is being populated with a custom adapter.  I have a pretty basic layout for each row of the the ListView (not even sure if this is applicable to my question):

```
 <RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/BaseStyle"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingRight="5dip"
android:paddingTop="8dip"
android:paddingBottom="8dip"
  >  

 <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"
    style="@style/BaseStyle.Title"
/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I'd like to overlay a single TextView at the bottom of the ListView, but not entirely sure how as working with Android layouts can be an exercise in futility. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your main layout with a FrameLayout and put the view that you want to be in overlay as last child.

```
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

        ...

        your ListView

        ...

        your text view (it is gonna be on top of your layout)
 </FrameLayout>
```

From your description I am not sure that this is what you are looking for, you should give some more info in your question, let me know.

If instead you are just talking about the TextView inside each list item then you just need to specifiy the alignment in your text view:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```